# Area 51 CAPTCHA?

Tags: discussion, area-51, captcha

Could someone tell me what the site looks for to track bots? [Here](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4659/does-this-overlap-too-much-with-existing-proposals/4721#4721) is my post...

> I believe that because the Classical languages and times are
>   intertwined, they should be in the same site. Notice that we don't
>   have a site for Python, C, and Java, but one big site for all
>   programming. I'm not suggesting a site for all languages, just that it
>   makes sense to keep this group of languages together.

I'll admit that it's not all that good, but the page got redirected to the [CAPTCHA](http://area51.stackexchange.com/captcha) page. Does it read the text and try to see if it is "regular" text?

Comment: No, I'm almost positive that the CAPTCHA trigger has nothing to do with the *content* of your post. Chances are, you hit a rate limit, which put you into the "suspected bot" category.

Comment: For Area 51 there is http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com, if the question is specific for Area 51.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The Establishment's comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126969/area-51-captcha#comment344593_126969) is probably correct:

> No, I'm almost positive that the CAPTCHA trigger has nothing to do with the content of your post. Chances are, you hit a rate limit, which put you into the "suspected bot" category.

The spam / captcha test is mostly based on how fast you post and not on the content (though we do look for some obvious spam flags in the content).